# Table of Contents using {ODS RTF CONTENTS=YES} doen't work

Tags: sas, rtf, tableofcontents, ods

I'm trying to create TOC using ODS RTF CONTENTS=YES.

I'm trying to use a method from [SAS Global Forum 2008](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/sgf2008/238-2008.pdf).

After I run the code I use word 2013 to to open the RTF file.
The file have two tables as I tried to create but When I'm trying to render the TOC (ctl+A -->F9) I'm getting the following error:

> No table of contents entries found.

my code is:

```
*create test data;
data try(rename=(T = DS));
    set Sashelp.BMT(obs=10);
run;


*create rtf file;
options nocenter nodate;
run; 

ods rtf file= 'test.RTF' 
startpage=keepn CONTENTS=YES;
ods noproctitle;
title;
RUN;
    ;first entry*
ODS PROCLABEL='Section 1: Personal Information';
proc freq data=try; table DS/norow nopercent nofreq;run;
    ;second entry*
ODS PROCLABEL='Section 2: Children in the home';
proc freq data=try; table Group/norow nopercent nofreq;run;

ods rtf close;
```

Comment: Your code has a few errors in various places. For example KEEPN is not a valid option for startpage and the first/second entry comments cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `TOC_DATA` to your `ODS RTF` statement, after fixing the other issues. Then it works as expected.

FYI-please use the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=odsug&docsetTarget=p1vvsv8ucnjzjnn1wq5wrlp74mdb.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p0pg2tmkd9x2own1rsrokb83vcsy) or a resource that's not a decade old - it will often not work because the software has changed.

Working Solution:

```
*create test data;
data try(rename=(T = DS));
    set Sashelp.BMT(obs=10);
run;


*create rtf file;
options nocenter nodate;
run; 

ods rtf file= '/home/fkhurshed/Demo1/test.RTF' 
startpage=never CONTENTS toc_data;
ods noproctitle;
title;
RUN;

ODS PROCLABEL='Section 1: Personal Information';
proc freq data=try; table DS/norow nopercent nofreq;run;

ODS PROCLABEL='Section 2: Children in the home';
proc freq data=try; table Group/norow nopercent nofreq;run;

ods rtf close;
```